# How to test custom event listener

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I am not sure how to test my simply event listener. As the listener returns no result but modifies the error event, I got stuck here:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Tests\Unit\Listener;

use App\Listener\ExceptionListener;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;

class ExceptionListenerTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testWithValidExceptionEvent(): void
    {
        $event = new ExceptionEvent(
            $this->createMock(HttpKernelInterface::class),
            $this->createMock(Request::class),
            1,
            $this->createMock(\Throwable::class)

        );
        new ExceptionListener($event);

        //I stuck here
    }
}
```

My listener looks like this:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Attribute\AsEventListener;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ExceptionEvent;

#[AsEventListener]
final class ExceptionListener
{
    public function __invoke(ExceptionEvent $event): void
    {
        $throwable = $event->getThrowable();

        $response = new JsonResponse([
            'message' => $throwable->getMessage(),
            'code' => $throwable->getCode()
        ]);

        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to ensure that the methods of the event object [are called](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/test-doubles.html?highlight=called#test-doubles-mock-objects-examples-subjecttest-php) in the listener.

Answer (score 1):

you will need an instance of EventDispatcher. to add your listener and trigger it .
Then you can use assertions from php-unit directly on the event object.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Tests\Unit\Listener;

use App\Listener\ExceptionListener;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use Throwable;

class ExceptionListenerTest extends TestCase
{

    /** @var EventDispatcher * */
    private $dispatcher;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
    }

    public function testWithValidExceptionEvent(): void
    {
        // add your instance listener
        $this->dispatcher->addListener('onKernelException', new ExceptionListener());


        $event = new ExceptionEvent(
            $this->createMock(HttpKernelInterface::class),
            $this->createMock(Request::class),
            1,
            $this->createMock(Throwable::class)

        );

        // dispatch your event

        $this->dispatcher->dispatch($event, 'onKernelException');

        // Assert
        self::assertInstanceOf(JsonResponse::class, $event->getResponse());
        self::assertIsString($event->getResponse()->getContent());
        self::assertStringContainsString('message', $event->getResponse()->getContent());
        self::assertStringContainsString('code', $event->getResponse()->getContent());
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't use `onKernelException` method in my case. My class is invokable.

Comment: it is not the method but rather the name of the event, we registered your listener which is invokable 
(listener invokable it is one of the ways to decide which method to call inside the listener d 'events)
it's the same thing For more details you can see the docs https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-listener .